# NGINX: control access to a location with both auth_basic and auth_ldap?

Tags: authentication, nginx

I am running NGINX 1.8.0 with nginx-auth-ldap. I have an application running at `/app` using `auth_ldap` for authentication/authorization. It works.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ...
    location /app/ {
        auth_ldap "Restricted";
        auth_ldap_servers test;
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to give access to an extra `bot` account to perform some automated maintenance (web API). I cannot create an LDAP account for `bot` for security reasons.

I tried to simultaneously use `auth_ldap` and `auth_basic` (with a single `bot` user for the latter) but any credentials result in a 401. Did I make a mistake, or is it simply not possible to get it to work this way?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ...
    location /app/ {
        auth_ldap "Restricted";
        auth_ldap_servers test;
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htaccess
        ...
    }
}
```

If this can't work, would you have any other recommendation how to proceed?

Note: I tried to mirror the application with `auth_basic` at a different location. The access control works, but the app hardcodes its URL: responses from `/app-auth-basic` contain links back to `/app`. I have no control over the application so this does not appear to lead anywhere.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ...
    location /app/ {
        auth_ldap "Restricted";
        auth_ldap_servers test;
        ...
    }
    location /app-auth-basic/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htaccess
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost correct but missing the `satisfy` directive:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ...
    location /app/ {
        satisfy any;

        auth_ldap "Restricted LDAP";
        auth_ldap_servers test;

        auth_basic "Restricted htaccess";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htaccess

        ...
    }
}
```

With this you will first be prompted by an auth dialog that says "Restricted LDAP" (that only accepts LDAP credentials). If you click cancel you will be prompted by another auth dialog that says "Restricted htaccess" (that only accepts users/passwords that are in your htaccess file). Note that the second dialog never appears if you already entered correct credentials in the first one.

Alternatively you can send htaccess credentials via `http://user:pass@your-domain.com` straight away to get in.